# Highchart, how to add commas to point data in tooltips

Tags: highcharts

My Highchart tooltip is formatted as follows:

```
$(function() {
   Highcharts.setOptions({
      chart: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: "Trebuchet MS"
            }
        },
       lang: {
           thousandsSeparator: ','
       }
   });

   // plot the chart
   new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graphContainer',
            type: 'area',
            marginBottom: 110
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f} m</b><br/>',
            crosshairs: true
        },
  ......
```

I know the ":,.0f" controls the format of the number, but I can't figure out how to add the "," in the thousands place instead of the " " blank space.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the setOptions before you created your chart?  It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fku1o2aw/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes, here's the start of my code:

$(function() {
   Highcharts.setOptions({
       lang: {
           thousandsSeparator: ','
       }
   });

   new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'graphContainer',
            type: 'area'
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f} m</b><br/>',
            crosshairs: true
        },

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is a typo. The global should be `thousandsSep` rather than `thousandsSeparator`, as described in the [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.thousandsSep).

Comment: `thousandsSep`* :)